# jQuery UI's cloned selectmenu not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I want to clone a `div` with different elements inside. One of those elements is a `select` converted to [selectmenu](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/).
The cloning works fine, except that the new `select` is not clickeable and it's items cannot be displayed.

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9t3Lf9ta/). Just click on the "clone" button and try to select the new `selectmenu`.

What would be a clean way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution to destroy selectmenu (Removes the selectmenu functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.)

so your code will be

```
$("select").selectmenu();

$("#btnClone").click(function()
{
    $( "select" ).selectmenu( "destroy" );
    $(".content:first").clone().appendTo(".container");
    $("select").selectmenu();

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/9t3Lf9ta/2/)

may be there are another solutions .. but till now thats what I reached so far

Comment: Your approach is not something that I would like to do, but no one else posted an answer and yours gets the job done.